# Как сделать в Android Studio, что бы одно меню было на всех layout на API 21?

Tags: java, android, menu

**Есть у меня активити MainActivity**

```
    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Intent intent = null;
        if (id == R.id.presents_my)
        {
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PresentsMy.class);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.Type6, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (intent != null) startActivity(intent);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

main.xml

```
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/my_gradient3"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorHeadText1"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorHeadText1"
        app:menu="@menu/main_drawer" />
```

content_main.xml (тут код N)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/my_gradient1"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml (тут код M)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorInput1"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <!-- кнопка добавить-->
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/addC"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorEndGrad1"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Есть у меня активити PresentsMy**

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Intent intent = null;
    if (id == R.id.presents_my)
    {
        intent = new Intent(PresentsMy.this, PresentsMy.class);
        Toast.makeText(PresentsMy.this, R.string.Type6, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    if (intent != null) startActivity(intent);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

content_presents_my.xml (тут код N)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/my_gradient1"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".PresentsMy"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_presents_my">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="104dp"
        android:text="@string/R1"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="92dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="190dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_presents_my.xml (тут код M)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PresentsMy">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorInput1"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_presents_my" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

В итоге кода я нажимаю на кнопку в меню  Main должен быть переход на другой уровень и с тем же меню. Но вылетает ошибка и программ закрывается.

Comment: вы хотите чтобы во всех активити был один DrawerLayout?

Comment: Да, что бы образно одна и та же шапка меню была на всех активити на которых мне нужно

Comment: воспользуйтесь одним активити с DrawerLayout, и фрагментами которые будут переключатся с помошью клика в NavigationView. Куча активити с одним и тем же DrawerLayout выглядит ужасно

Comment: Я понимаю что через фрагменты нужно так как я сам не хочу что бы был один и тот же код, но не могу понять как это реализовать, есть пример?

Comment: Просто Fragment - это api 27. А я на Api 21 рассчитывал делать.

Comment: Все нашел куда копать и урок, спасибо. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGcMLu1GJEc